# Cocos2dx-3.0 use setSearchPaths adapted to screen size doesn't work

Tags: c++, ios, adapter, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Problem is after i use setSearchPaths() to set different image path for different screen size, look like the project get image from image path random.

For example:if screen's height is 1136, the search path is "iphoneBig" and the project should use image of path "iphoneBig", but sometimes the project use the image of path "iphoneMid".

I put my code snippets at here:

```
typedef struct tagResource

{

cocos2d::Size size;

char directory[100];

}Resource;

static Resource smallResource = { cocos2d::Size::Size(480, 320), "iphoneSmall" };

static Resource iPhone4Resource = { cocos2d::Size::Size(960, 640), "iphoneMid" };

static Resource iPhone5Resource = { cocos2d::Size::Size(1136, 640), "iphoneBig" };

cocos2d::Size frameSize = pEGLView->getVisibleSize();

pEGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(frameSize.width, frameSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);



if (frameSize.height > 960)

{

    std::string str(iPhone5Resource.directory);

    std::vector<std::string> vtStr;

    vtStr.push_back(str);

    cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchPaths(vtStr);

}

else if (frameSize.height > smallResource.size.height)

{

    std::string str(iPhone4Resource.directory);

    std::vector<std::string> vtStr;

    vtStr.push_back(str);

    cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchPaths(vtStr);

}
```

Who can tell me the reason? A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior described arises from the fact that the various folders of resources have been added as groups and when Xcode creates the executable it copies all the resource files into a single path, and then identical names will be overwritten. The order in which the files are copied can make sure that the file really present in the app is different from run to run.

When you add resources to your project you have to create a folder reference (not a group) especially if more than one of the resource folders share a common filename:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this issue was driving me crazy! @Dracuuula should accept this answer....

Comment: @louissmr : It was driving me crazy too. :-)